# Angular 4 : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', but only with post requests

Tags: javascript, angular, api, cors

I know there already is a few questions on the topic, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I am fairly new to angular 4, and I am trying to build a simple create/update/delete service using an external custom API.

I first had issues with CORS, but that was fixed by setting the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the server side of the api.

Now my GET/PATCH and DELETE request work fine, but my "POST" still catches an error.

And here's the "odd" part.

When I check into the "network" tab of google chrome's developper tools, I see both "OPTIONS" and then "POST" request (as angular is supposed to do), but only the "OPTIONS" has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3003" in the response headers.

However they both send a "200" response code. (Here are [some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URViD.png))

Why would the post break wheras the others work fine ?

Here are some code samples from my service :

```
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

// works
update(id: number, fields: any): Promise<Tag> {
    const url = `${this.tagsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http
        .patch(url, JSON.stringify(fields), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

// doesn't work
create(tagName: string, tagType: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.tagsUrl, JSON.stringify({name: tagName, tagType: tagType}), {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can bring !

Michael

Comment: This is not an Angular related issue. It's the backend that does something wrong. I would recommend running Angular on the same host as your backend. So it skip the **preflight** it can become a pain.

Comment: I see. I'll try to find a solution with the person in charge of the backend then.

But how come the problem only appears with "post" and not any other method ?

Comment: Then the post is not allowed by the backed. I'm not sure if preflight only comes with POST but just google it and you will find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found where the problem came from.

It came from my local server configuration. I had to uncomment this line from my php.ini :

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

It now works as intended.

Thank you for your help.